# Recycler view adapter remove items

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have two activities: HomePage and MyFavorites. Both have recycler views with items (similar to facebook posts) each item has a button, when you click on it, the item will be shown in the recycler view for MyFav activity. The code for when the button is clicked is in the Adapter class for the recycler view (both activities use the same adapter). Now when a user click on the button for the second time (while the user is in MyFav activity) it means that this specific item should be removed from the recycler view in MyFav activity, but when the button is clicked for a second time while the user is using/opening the HomePage activity the item shouldn’t be removed, the button will turn from red to white ONLY . How can i remove the item only from the recycler view in MyFav activity without removing it from the HomePage activity (since both use the same adapter for their recycler view) without making a new adapter?

If i create separate adapter class for each activity, is it good practice? Since the same code will be duplicated twice with minor changes.

Note: the button (Fav button) is a checkbox with a heart shaped icon, the color is initially white, it will turn red when clicked for the first time, and white when clicked again and so on..

Comment: Sorry I tried to make it simple but turns out i did the exact opposite

Comment: When the user is on the home page screen, the item (post) should not be removed when the user “unfav” it. But when the user is on the my favorites activity/screen, and they “unfav” the post it should be removed immediately from the recycler view in this activity..

Comment: could you please share the code